# Unable to clear snapshot using Nodetool. Snapshot is never deleted

Tags: cassandra, datastax

When I run nodetool clearsnapshot I get the normal "Requested clearing snapshot(s)" message, but the snapshot is never removed.  What can I do to troubleshoot why this is occurring?  Is it acceptable for me to just manually remove the snapshot directories from the tablespace directories as a workaround for this?

nodetool clearsnapshot 1472489985541

```
Requested clearing snapshot(s) for [1472489985541]
```

nodetool listsnapshots |  awk '{print $1}' | grep ^1 | sort -u

```
1472489985541
1473165734236
1473690660090
1474296554367
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to delete a snapshot from all keyspaces using the snapshot name, you must specify the -t flag in your clearsnapshot command.

Comment: Hi, I am unable to take any snapshot for a table, it is saying `Requested creating snapshot(s) for [testkeyspace] with snapshot name [1564405195160]` . Why it is not creating ?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it acceptable for me to just manually remove the snapshot directories from the tablespace directories as a workaround for this?

Yes, you can always safely remove the snapshots directories manually. They are just hard links to actual SSTables

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure if there was some reference to them in a system table somewhere for nodetool to use to keep track of them.